# Code to check if matrices can be solved with Jacobi method not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def checkJacobi(m):
    row = m.shape[0]
    col = m.shape[1]
    solv = 0
    for i in range(row):
        x = abs(m[i,i])
        y = 0
        for j in range(col):
            y = y + abs(m[i,j])
        y = y - x
        if (y < x):
            solv = solv + 1
    if (solv == col):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This is my code so far to simply check matrices to see if they can be solved using the Jacobi method (Jacobi Method can only be used when the absolute value of the diagonal elements of each row dominate the sum of the absolute value for the other elements in the same row). I tested it out with matrices that should work and they are returning False. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Not seeing where you're taking the absolute value of `y` after subtracting out `x`.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, this isn't needed: one should compute the sum of absolute values, not the absolute value of the sum.

Comment: @ForceBru: Oh, you're right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix

The test is `abs(m[i, i]) >= sum(abs(m[i, j]) for j in range(cols)) - abs(m[i, i])`. So, your code should be:

```
if y <= x: # not y < x
    solv = solv + 1
```

Your code is checking for *strict* diagonal dominance, while the Jacobi method works even with simple "non-strict" one.

Comment: @M.Ash, for example?

Comment: this is a matrix that is solved when using a Jacobi function code, A = np.matrix([[6,2,-1,4],[1,5,1,3],[2,1,4,27]])

Comment: @M.Ash, this "Jacobi function code" is incorrect because the Jacobi method only works with square (NxN) matrices, but your matrix is 3x4.

Comment: You're right. The Jacobi function code was provided by my professor so I am not sure what he was going for when asking to make this code. I will contact him about the error. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score -1):

Main mistake was (y < x) - solve + 1 -> must be (y <=x)

Furthermore mapping absolute value onto row might be a bit cleaner:

```
def checkJacobi(m):
row = m.shape[0]
col = m.shape[1]
solv = 0
for i in range(row):
    m[i] = list(map(abs,m[i]))
    x = m[i,i]
    y = 0
    for j in range(col):
        y = y + m[i,j]
    y = y - x
    if (y <= x):
        solv = solv + 1
if (solv == row):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: The Jacobi method only works for square matrices, so `row == col`.

Comment: Also, why do `list(map(abs,m[i]))`, if you can do `abs(m[i])`, which is way faster.